# How can I apply a different colour to ggplot bars in R, according to a variable?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm a new entry in Stackoverflow.

I want to represent this dataframe in a ggplot (I show you only the first rows):

```
word   word_count    sentiment      cols
1 love      28577          joy lightblue
2 love      28577     positive     green
3 time      12900 anticipation    purple
4 baby       5748          joy lightblue
5 baby       5748     positive     green
6 shit       5384        anger    orange
```

The current code I'm using is this, to represent the first 20 words and corresponding sentiments:

```
ggplot(temp_table[1:20,], aes(x=word, y=word_count, fill=sentiment)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("orange","purple", "brown", "grey", "lightblue", "red", "green", "blue", "yellow", "lightgreen")) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, hjust=1))
```

and the resulting graph:

[image]

My aim is to maintain the current legend (and the **correspondence between colour and sentiment**) also when I display only 10 or 15 rows of the dataset. For example, if I plot only 10 rows, the resulting plot is this:

```
ggplot(temp_table[1:10,], aes(x=word, y=word_count, fill=sentiment)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("orange","purple", "brown", "grey", "lightblue", "red", "green", "blue", "yellow", "lightgreen")) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, hjust=1))
```

and the colours are completely wrong:

[image]

Is it possible to create a "fixed" legend with fixed pairs "sentiment-colour"? I hope the question is clear! Thank you.

Comment: Yes if you supply a named vector to the `values` argument, it will be fixed item-colour pairs. For example `values = c(anger = "orange", anticipation = "purple", ...)`.

Comment: It was much simpler than I thought, thank you so much!